# Postgresql stored procedures transferring

Tags: database, postgresql, stored-procedures, transfer

Is there are way to get all stored procedures from 1st database and transfer it to the 2nd in creating database script? (without using pgAdmin or stuff like)

Comment: Might work using `pg_dump` with the `--section=post-data --schema-only` options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really interested only in the functions you can query `pg_proc` catalog and grab the `CREATE FUNCTION` statements for a given schema (let's say `public`):

```
$ psql -AXtqc "SELECT pg_get_functiondef(oid)||';' FROM pg_proc p WHERE p.pronamespace = (SELECT oid FROM pg_namespace WHERE nspname = 'public')" your_first_database
```

If you really want only one step:

```
$ psql -AXtqc "SELECT pg_get_functiondef(oid)||';' FROM pg_proc p WHERE p.pronamespace = (SELECT oid FROM pg_namespace WHERE nspname = 'public')" your_first_database | psql your_second_database
```

This is good for one-time-tasks, but not very good for definitive scripts, as the query may change from one version to other of PostgreSQL. Also, it consider function created by extensions as if they were not.